# Interface method overloading

Tags: c#, interface

Having two interface and a class. Please see the below code

```
public interface IBook {
bool Initilize();
}
public interface IGoodBook : IBook
{
string Pages {get; set;}
}
public class Books : IGoodBook{

public string Pages {get; set;}

public bool Initilize(){
    Console.WriteLine("This is Initilize")
}
}
```

I want to pass few parameters / arguments into class Books Initilize method, how can I do this without modifying interface IBook Initilize() method.
Please advise all posibile option in this regards,

Comment: You can. However, it's not a good idea to have `Initialize` method in an interface in the first place, because initialization is done by constructors, so by the time `Initialize` is called the object must be initialized.

Comment: Initialize is used to Initialize device here!

Comment: Can't you pass those argument in the constructor? Otherwise, if you can't use the abstraction then what's the point?

Answer (score 1):

```
public interface IBook {
bool Initilize();
}
public interface IGoodBook : IBook
{
string Pages {get; set;}
}
public class Books : IGoodBook{

public string Pages {get; set;}

public bool Initilize(){
    Console.WriteLine("This is Initilize")
// you need to return bool in your first message still
}

public bool Initilize(string test)
{
  Console.WriteLine("paramter passed" + test);
  return true;
}
}
```

Comment: any-other better way! because  public bool Initilize() is useless here...

Comment: hmm my other suggestion would be to alter the contract in IBook interface using params https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/params but you stated that you did not want to alter that.